# Google DevTools missing UI info

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get a snapshot of heap usage of my JavaScript test using Google DevTools. I used this site: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling
along with Windows 7 and Google Chrome.

The problem is that I need to see the memory metrics (bytes vs kilobytes) under Retained and Shallow size, but it isn't showing. I tried to look online, and mess with DevTools myself, but can't seem to find a way to display this.

Google's own site just goes right from here:
[image]

to here:
[image]

without explaining how they did it... Now I see that in the second image, they are using MacOS. Could this be why? I COULD infer what the size metrics are based on these two images, but I really would like to *know*.

Here is what I see when I go on to DevTools:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If no one knows how to do that, could they at least tell me what the numbers and percentages under Shallow and Retained size mean? I know what Shallow and Retained memory is, but I have no idea what these numbers or percentages represent, because they can't quite be Bytes, and the percentages don't add up. I tried to watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ugr9BJqIs but they skipped what those columns mean. The guy said in the beginning "on my machine, objects are 36 bytes", but that doesn't explain the white space between the bigger numbers, or the percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot with 'retaining paths' are quite old. The fresh versions show retaining tree.
I've created a bug about this. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240872

The retaining tree will be nonempty if you select a particular object in the upper window.

If object A is the only retainer for another object B and the second object the only retainer for a 100Mb array C then you will see three objects in the list.

The small object A with retained size = sizeof C + sizeof B + sizeof A = ~100Mb.

The small object B with retained size = sizeof C + sizeof B = ~100Mb but less than retained size for A.

And big array C with shallow size = retained size = 100Mb.

At the same time the total size of the heap will be equal to the retained size of object A.
So the sum of retained sizes or percents is the strange number that means nothing.

If you drop the link between B and C then C will be collected.

If you drop the link between A and B the B and C will be collected.

If you drop the link to A then A and B and C will be collected.

If you create a link from an object D to C and take another snapshot then the retained sizes of A and B become smaller because C will not be collected if you drop the link between B and C or between A and B or from somewhere to A because there is a link from D to C.

See the doc for yourkit http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/sizes.jsp

Answer (score 1):

First thing I asked when learning to use the profiler. Ridiculous it is still not labelled properly.

> [Note: Both the Shallow and Retained size columns represent data in
>   bytes.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling?hl=vi)